# Program Mathematica - Parametric Plot

Tags: plotting, symbolic, parametric-functions

In program Mathematica 11

```
x[t_] := Exp[-p*t]*Cos[c*t]
y[t_] := Exp[-q*t]*Sin[d*t]

ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

But

[image]

What is going wrong?

Comment: YOu haven't specified values for `p`, `c`, `q`, or `d`.

Comment: For example {p,1,3} ?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by `{p, 1, 3}`. The point that I was making is that you can't plot a function that has variables left undefined. If you put numbers in for `p`, `c`, `q`, and `d`, the plot will work just fine.

Comment: march means that you should assign values to p,c,q and d. Try for example `{p,c,q,d}={1,2,3,4}`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign values to the parameters, e.g.

```
p = q = c = d = 1;

x[t_] := Exp[-p*t]*Cos[c*t]
y[t_] := Exp[-q*t]*Sin[d*t]

ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

[image]